# (JUCE Framework) juce::dsp::Convolution effect does not work with bluetooth headphones in Android Application

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, convolution, juce

I have created a simple Audio Player Android application that provides various DSP effects. All the effects are working great, but the IMPULSE effect I created with the DSP Convolution Class does not work with Bluetooth headphones. The sound gets distorted and extremeley chopped. The Impulse Convolution works fine with the phone's built-in speaker, but it gets distorted when I switch to Bluetooth.

How can I fix this ?  How can Bluetooth effect JUCE convolution  DSP ?